# Why does pivot_wider convert numeric to list type?

Tags: r, list, pivot-table, numeric

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- read.csv(file= "./b002003.csv", header = TRUE)%>%

pivot_wider(
names_from = TRIAL_INDEX,
values_from = RIGHT_GAZE_X)

data$rowmeans <-rowMeans(select(data,c(3,6)))
```

When I converted the long table to wide table, the column type changed to be list.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/349zT.png)
Because I want to average column(3,6), so I need the data to be numeric or a method to average the according vector in list.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a look [how to make a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), i.e. provide example data. Then it's easier to help you, thanks!

Comment: I guess your data.frame contains some duplicates from `TRIAL_INDEX` so that the mapping to the wide table is not unique. If you want to average duplicate entries, you could use `mean` for `values_fn`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I may be behind the times, but what is `\<-`?